# Prestashop 1.6 -> Change Order State by ajax, errors with email

Tags: php, ajax, prestashop, tcpdf

I need for a module to change the order state of an order by ajax.
I'm currently doing it with the function from the Order Class :

```
$o = new Order($id_order);
$o->setCurrentState($id_state,$this->context->employee->id);
```

I then recover the new order state info in the JSON response to display it on the page.
It works perfectly for every order states, except the ones that send emails with attachment (invoice.pdf or delivery.pdf -- Payment accepted for example)

Here are the errors I get in the JSON response :

```
Notice: Undefined index: startx in C:\wamp64\www\tdc\tools\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 24628
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0008  386736  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.1224  2348784 Dispatcher->dispatch( ) ...\index.php:58
3   0.2177  3387304 AdminOrderManagerController->run( ) ...\Dispatcher.php:367
4   0.3167  4328416 AdminOrderManagerController->postProcess( ) ...\Controller.php:178
5   0.3177  4329424 AdminOrderManagerController->ajaxProcessChangeOrderState( ) ...\AdminController.php:897
6   0.3277  4625976 Order->setCurrentState( )   ...\adminordermanager.php:407
7   0.4096  4949648 OrderHistory->addWithemail( )   ...\Order.php:1569
8   0.4609  4974424 OrderHistory->sendEmail( )  ...\OrderHistory.php:419
9   0.4728  6633024 PDF->render( )  ...\OrderHistory.php:470
10  4.9544  7630400 PDFGenerator->render( ) ...\PDF.php:108
11  4.9544  7630400 PDFGenerator->Output( ) ...\PDFGenerator.php:207
12  4.9544  7630400 PDFGenerator->Close( )  ...\tcpdf.php:8864
13  4.9580  7636848 PDFGenerator->endPage( )    ...\tcpdf.php:3869
14  4.9580  7636848 PDFGenerator->setFooter( )  ...\tcpdf.php:4021
15  4.9588  7639840 PDFGenerator->Footer( ) ...\tcpdf.php:4471
16  4.9588  7639840 PDFGenerator->writeHTML( )  ...\PDFGenerator.php:172
17  5.1563  7768440 PDFGenerator->closeHTMLTagHandler( )    ...\tcpdf.php:23219
```

And there is like 6 other like that, but the strangest thing is even if I get those errors, the email is still sent, with in attachment the correct PDF, rendered without any errors...

I could ignore the error that I get in the JSON response since the email and pdf are correctly sent, however with those errors I can't retrieve the new order state information in the JSON response to then display them on the page.

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the TCPDF parser can't parse your HTML.

Remove all ".tpl" files in your "pdf" folder from your theme folder to make sure that the **default PrestaShop files** are in use

Comment: Indeed you were right,
I removed every TPL from my theme pdf folder, and it worked.